# Rename incrementing JSON objects in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, object

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
"153689763780624385": {
    "1": {
        "author": "Mike",
        "date": "05/06/2022, 12:00:57"

    },
    "2": {
        "author": "Mike",
        "date": "05/06/2022, 13:29:43"

    },
    "3": {
        "author": "Jan01p",
        "date": "05/7/2022, 16:01:22"
    }
}
```

What I am doing is accessing my JSON, and deleting the 2nd object key in the json file. With the following code.

```
with open("pins.json", "r+") as f:
    p = json.load(f)
gid = "153689763780624385"
del p[gid]["2"]
with open("pins.json", "w+") as fp:
     json.dump(p, fp, indent=4)
```

Now my JSON looks like this

```
"153689763780624385": {
    "1": {
        "author": "Mike",
        "date": "05/06/2022, 12:00:57"

    }
    "3": {
        "author": "Jan01p",
        "date": "05/7/2022, 16:01:22"
    }
}
```

My goal here is to use a loop of some sort to rename all the following keys to be in order. So change `3` to `2`. Name `4` to `3` and so on. The JSON is much larger just made it shorter for asking purposes. What's a good way to rename the keys to go in incrementing order? So far i'm thinking of dict.pop in a for loop. But can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your keys are all numbers as strings and you just want to rest them 1. Using the `dict.pop()` method:

```
value_to_remove = 2

with open("pins.json", "r+") as f:
    p = json.load(f)
gid = "153689763780624385"

del p[gid][str(value_to_remove)]

for key, values in p[gid].items():
    if int(key) > value_to_remove:
        p[gid][str(int(key)-1)] = p[gid].pop(str(key))

with open("pins.json", "w+") as fp:
     json.dump(p, fp, indent=4)
```

If the key value saved in `gid` is the only one you want to be removed the `"2"` key. Then it is ok. If you want to implement this for every 'first key', you can iterate over every first keys in the json dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below logic to reorder all the keys.

```py
my_dict1 = {"1": "a", "3": "b", "4": "c", "5": "d"}
my_dict2 = {str(i+1):v for i, v in enumerate(my_dict1.values())}

print(my_dict2)
# {'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c', '4': 'd'}
```

This solution can only be used for Python version 3.7 and newer, as dictionaries before this version are unordered. *If you want to keep them ordered by date.*

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. I forgot to mention though I also have another field of a different "gid" and this overwrites it. I'll play around with it so it just replaces the above one. But if I can't get it i'll ask.

Comment: If you are overwriting anything else beside the keys in the targeted dictionary, the logic have been implemented wrong. Make sure the correct dictionary and keys are targeted.